# Invalid problem to show $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ is not complete with respect to the $L^1$-Norm

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

I know it has been asked many times to show that the space $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ is not complete with respect to the $L^1$-norm, but I was given to show it using one *particular* sequence and at the moment I think the problem statement is false.

I was asked to consider the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with

$$f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{30pt} x \mapsto \begin{cases} xn & 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{n} \\ 2 - xn & \frac{1}{n} \leq x < \frac{2}{n} \\ 0 & \frac{2}{n} \leq x < 1\end{cases}$$

to show that the given space is not complete, but I feel confident that the sequence of functions will converge to the constant zero-map in the $L^1$-Norm. Therefore this sequence is not suitable for the proof.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It does converge to zero (in $L^1$), so this is not a counterexample. Try a sequence of continuous approximations to $1_{[{1 \over 2},1]}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. I already know some sequences for a proof, but was given this once explicitly and thought something was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that it really is the collection of equivalence classes one needs to consider not just one particular element of the class. So, the counterexample needs to be more robust...